# Unable to successfully call startRecorder(uri: ...) from the flutter_sound package

Tags: flutter, audio, dart

I am trying to get the simple functionality of the flutter_sound package to work. I am approaching this by first being able to start recording. It seems as if I currently have an issue where, even when I include the Uri to where I want to save these files, as well as the type of audio format I want it to export these files as I get an issue saying:

```
flutter: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'startRecorder' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: startRecorder(codec: Instance of 't_CODEC', uri: "/Users/<user-name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CEC7EE26-9400-479B-85EB-06728074F7C0/data/Containers/Data/Application/4C726628-AE3B-42E7-8C6A-4B239AFDFAE6/Library/Caches/audio.aac")
```

I checked the directory and I do not see an `audio.aac` file appearing, so when I tried to create a file through the terminal by using `touch audio.aac` and tried to record, I still got the same error. So I am assuming that I need to be able to create that file in their somehow, or that I might not even understand what the issue is at all. I am really lost, have had other developers try to help and can't find resources on how to solve this issue.

In my pubspec.yaml I have set the flutter_sound version to be as seen below:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_sound: ^2.0.3
```

I have included the necessary permissions in my Info.plist and in my AndroidManifest.xml.

I will be posting, what I feel is needed code below.

```dart
class _AudioRecorderState extends State<AudioRecorder> {
  String _recordedFilePath;
  bool _isRecording = false;
  bool _isPlaying = false;
  StreamSubscription _recorderSubscription;
  StreamSubscription _dbPeakSubscription;
  StreamSubscription _playerSubscription;
  FlutterSound flutterSound;

  String _recorderTxt = '00:00:00';
  String _playerTxt = '00:00:00';
  double _dbLevel;

  double sliderCurrentPosition = 0.0;
  double maxDuration = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FlutterSound flutterSound = new FlutterSound();
    flutterSound.setSubscriptionDuration(0.01);
    flutterSound.setDbPeakLevelUpdate(0.8);
    flutterSound.setDbLevelEnabled(true);
    initializeDateFormatting();
  }

  void startRecorder() async {
    try {
      Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      File filePath = File('${tempDir.path}/audio.aac');
      String path = await flutterSound.startRecorder(uri: filePath.path, codec: t_CODEC.CODEC_AAC);
      print('startRecorder: $path');

      _recorderSubscription = flutterSound.onRecorderStateChanged.listen((e) {
        DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
            e.currentPosition.toInt(),
            isUtc: true);
        String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_US').format(date);

        this.setState(() {
          this._recorderTxt = txt.substring(0, 8);
        });
      });
      _dbPeakSubscription =
          flutterSound.onRecorderDbPeakChanged.listen((value) {
        print("got update -> $value");
        setState(() {
          this._dbLevel = value;
        });
      });

      this.setState(() {
        this._isRecording = true;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print('startRecorder error: $err');
    }
  }
```

If you would like to see my `Widget Build(...){...}` or any other part of my code please let me know.

Comment: hey bro, will you please post full code here for start and stop recording, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not initialising your flutterSound instance correctly

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //FlutterSound flutterSound = new FlutterSound();
    //you already created flutterSound at the top
    flutterSound = new FlutterSound();
    flutterSound.setSubscriptionDuration(0.01);
    flutterSound.setDbPeakLevelUpdate(0.8);
    flutterSound.setDbLevelEnabled(true);
    initializeDateFormatting();
  }
```